# Какие варианты запуска множества скриптов, с мониторингом статуса состояния каждого скрипта + лог работы

Tags: python, linux, скрипт

Занимаюсь ботоводством. Яп - питон.
До этого использовал tmux, чтобы поднимать своих ботов, но столкнулся с проблемой, а именно - tmux ест слишком много оперативки + после каждого рестарта приходится поднимать все сессии снова, руками. А так же нельзя сразу проверить статус работы скрипта (как это сделано к примеру в systemd).

Суть:
Хочу найти инструмент с помощи которого можно запускать неограниченное количество скриптов, смотреть статус каждой сессии, как это сделано в systemd.

Сразу скажу, что этот список инструментов: tmux, systemd, crontab - мне не подходит.
Самым приятным был systemd, но в нём не работают некоторые скрипты, которые связаны с отправкой файлов (фото, видео). Из под консоли все работает, а вот в systemd выдаёт ошибку, мол не смог отправить фото\видео.

В общем прошу вашей помощи!

Comment: Может supervisor?

Comment: Да, тоже об этом подумал. Сам им никогда не пользовался, но вроде там даже веб мониторинг есть и можно от туда стопать\запускать скрипты, что очень удобно.

Answer (score 0):

docker + docker-compose:

За оперативку не скажу, смотрите.

Состояние: `docker ps`, `docker stats`.

Логи: `docker logs`.

"некоторые скрипты" можно попробовать с docker-compose с `tty: true` и/или `init: true` в конфигурации.

Comment: `restart: always` -- поднимать автоматом после рестарта